# Removing first ^M from each line of file

Tags: text-processing

**Data starts on the second line.**  Is there a simple script or utility to remove the first instance of `^m` **on each line of data?**

The problem can also be rephrased as: how can every second (even) instance of `^m` be removed?  Looking forward interesting (clever) responses.  Preferably in Ubuntu or similar.

[image]

Raw data for the clever to cut, paste and parse:

```
Date,From,To,Flight_Number,Airline,Distance,Duration,Seat,Seat_Type,Class,Reason,Plane,Registration,Trip,Note,From_OID,To_OID,Airline_OID,Plane_OID^M
- -,JFK,OTBD,American Airlines (AA),American Airlines,6687,13:52,,,,,777^M,,,"Direct",3797,2241,24^M
- -,JFK,OTBD,Qatar Airways (QR),Qatar Airways,6687,13:52,,,,,77W^M,,,"Direct",3797,2241,4091^M
```

That being said, the reason for posing this question is the unexpected ^m is causing import problems into Libre-Office Calc (spreadsheet): it cause an expected new-line.

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu you shouldn't need anything more clever than `sed 's/\r//' file` to remove the *first* carriage return on each (newline delimited) line

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to keep the file in DOS format (CRLF line endings) we can cheat; remove *all* the CR's and then add them back at the end of line.

So

```
tr -d '\015' < srcfile | unix2dos > newfile
```

EDIT for detailed description:

The

```
tr -d '\015'
```

will strip out *all* of the control-M characters from the file.  `-d` to `tr` means "delete" and `'\015'` is the control-M character in octal format.

The

```
unix2dos
```

will convert any LF (linefeed; control-J; ) characters to CRLF by inserting a CR (control-M) before the LF character; this converts a unix format text file to a DOS format text file.

Put the two together and we delete all the rogue ^M's and ensure the only ones are at the end of each line.

Comment: This is clever and I have confirmed it works correctly.  A good high-level explanation provided, however, a more detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Edited with details.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '2,$s/\r//' filename
```

What it does:

1. `-i.bak` adds a backup of the original file as `filename.bak`.
2. `2,$` is to start on the second line and continue to the end of the file.
3. `s/\r//` removes the first occurrence of the carriage return (^M in the screenshot) on each line.

Sample command using posted excerpt, where I have manually entered the carriage returns in vi:

```
$ cat -A test_sed
Date,From,To,Flight_Number,Airline,Distance,Duration,Seat,Seat_Type,Class,Reason,Plane,Registration,Trip,Note,From_OID,To_OID,Airline_OID,Plane_OID^M$
- -,JFK,OTBD,American Airlines (AA),American Airlines,6687,13:52,,,,,777^M,,,"Direct",3797,2241,24^M$
- -,JFK,OTBD,Qatar Airways (QR),Qatar Airways,6687,13:52,,,,,77W^M,,,"Direct",3797,2241,4091^M$

$ sed -i.bak '2,$s/\r//' test_sed

$ cat -A test_sed
Date,From,To,Flight_Number,Airline,Distance,Duration,Seat,Seat_Type,Class,Reason,Plane,Registration,Trip,Note,From_OID,To_OID,Airline_OID,Plane_OID^M$
- -,JFK,OTBD,American Airlines (AA),American Airlines,6687,13:52,,,,,777,,,"Direct",3797,2241,24^M$
- -,JFK,OTBD,Qatar Airways (QR),Qatar Airways,6687,13:52,,,,,77W,,,"Direct",3797,2241,4091^M$
```

Comment: This answer is articulated in a top-down manner that provides the solution, step-by-step solution-explanation and demonstration of results.  The response indicate a clear understanding of the problem and is the model for instructional value

Answer (score 2):

(Based on the fact that your image shows the `^M` in blue, as opposed to the normal white, I assume you mean the carriage return (CR) character, and not a literal caret+M combination. (Yes, this is a case where posting text as an image can actually be helpful.))

1) Since you're feeding the data to LibreOffice, you could see if it would handle Unix style linefeeds (just LF, instead of CRLF) nicely, and just remove all carriage returns altogether:

```
tr -d '\r' < input > output
```

2) If you want to keep the DOS-style CRLF line endings, and to just remove the CR:s that are in the middle of the line (i.e. not immediately followed by LF), you could do this in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\r(?!\n)//g' < input > output
```

`s/xxx/yyy/g` replaces all occurrences of `xxx` with `yyy`, `\r` is interpreted as the carriage return character, and `(?!\n)` means "not followed by `\n`", where `\n` is the newline/linefeed character. The replacement is empty so matches are removed.

You could do something similar with `sed`, but the `\r` escape isn't supported on all versions of `sed`, and entering the `ctrl-M` character literally on the command line is somewhat annoying to do. (Ubuntu would have GNU sed, which supports it, but it also has Perl, so.)

I specifically ignored everything you said about the first occurrence on each line, and about ignoring the first line, since I find it slightly fragile to trust on the input to always contain exactly the correct amount of spurious extra control characters. (What if some line happens to have two `^M`:s, or none?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do by using SED on both `GNU` and `BSD` versions to remove **the first** occurrence of something:

```
sed '2,/RE/s/\^M//' yourFile
```

And here is what you can do to remove **the second** - **or nth** - occurrence:

```
sed '2,/RE/s/\^M//2' yourFile
```

# The first one is the same as `sed '2,/RE/s/\^M//1' yourFile`

**N.B.** `/RE/` would stop the replace if some line contains `RE`. You can fill it with whatsoever else. OR you can just use `sed '2,$s/\^M//' yourFile`, the choice is yours.

Comment: This would stop the replace if some line contained the letters `RE`, right?

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes mate, right, you can fill it with whatsoever you want. or just use: sed `'2,/RE/s/\^M//' yourFile`, OR you can Use the patter from the first line and restrict it by 'Date': `sed '0,/Date/s/\^M//' yourFile`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the subject: *remove every other CR character in the file*, with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='\r' '{ORS = NR % 2 ? RT : ""; print}' < infile > outfile
```

It sets the (input) record separator to CR, and sets the output record separator to RT (the record terminator for this record which could be CR or nothing if it's the last record and the input doesn't end in a CR character) only for even records (when `NR % 2 != 0`).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the CRs not at the end of the line with `sed`, you can do:

```
CR=$(printf '\r')
sed -e :1 -e "s/$CR\(.\)/\1/g;t1" < infile > outfile
```

Or since you're on Ubuntu, where `sed` is GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E ':1;s/\r(.)/\1/g;t1' < infile > outfile
```

It looks for CRs followed by a character (which happens for all CRs except those at the end of the line), and replaces them with that character (captured in `\1`). It does it repeatedly in a loop to account for consecutive CRs.

Now, it it's only for importing in a Unix software, you might as well remove *all* CRs, so you end up with a text file in Unix format (CRLF line endings are only for Microsoft OSes, you're quite lucky that that software understands CRLF terminated lines in the first place):

```
tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile
```